Change UsersRoles table PK
In Entity Framework Core 8, I'd like to change the default PK for UsersRoles table, currently set as follows:
table.PrimaryKey("PK_UsersRoles", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });

to something else (e.g. including an additional column).
Is there a way to achieve the result using migrations?
I can change table configuration using SQL DDL statements, but I don't know if it is possible to do it using migrations.

Create an empty Migration, then add code to have it execute the raw SQL statement(s).

Mind that this isn't something you should do light-headed. Altering the PK will have significant impact. Maybe it's even impossible (practicably). Does anything relate to those keys?
